# Get libgsl.so.19 for a program to run; have gsl-2.5 but that has libgsl.so.23

Tags: version, gsl

I am trying to install a program that is trying to call libgsl.so.19. The version of gsl I have (2.5) installed with libgsl.so.23 only. Which versions would have libgsl.so.19 (rather than downloading randomly) or what do I need to do to get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine pointed me to version 2.3 which contains the libgsl.so.19 and worked for me